# How to Put Drawer below the Header React-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new in react and I have useStyles in my code for changing the style of the drawer

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   drawer: {
       marginTop: 56,
   }
}));
class PageMenu extends React.Component {
GetMenuItems() {
var classes = useStyle();
<div>
   <Drawer
      open={this.props.DrawerOpen}
      anchor="right"
      variant="persistent"
      onClose={this.fixthew}
      classes = {classes.drawer}
   >
      ---some element------
   </Drawer>
<\div>
}
}
render() {
  return(
     <div>
        {GetMenuItems}
     </div>
  )
}
```

the problem is `ReferenceError: useStyle is not defined` and `GetMenuItems` should be before the render

Comment: You have defined `useStyles ` on the top, but you are using it as `useStyle`. The letter 's' is missing, so why the reference error.

And the way you have defined `GetMenuItems` and the way you are referencing in the render is wrong. If you want to use it as a property of the PageMenu class then the naming should be `getMenuItems`.
Either bind this with PageMenu class then use it as {this.getMenuItems()}
or  create `GetMenuItems` as separate functional component, then use it as <GetMenuItems />

Comment: u did not gave feedback that  you accept any answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `withStyles` instead of `makeStyles` for Class Components.

Comment: this is my main problem `var classes = useStyle();` i changed to `makeStyles ` to `withStyles ` but still it's not defined

Comment: you have to import it `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

Answer (score 0):

many mistakes:

1. You are using the `useStyles` hook in a class component (hooks are only for functional components)..
2. You defining the component as one of class methud... u shouldn't do so..
3. You pass the class in the classes prop instead of in className prop

instead use a functional component like so:

```
function MenuItems(){
    var classes = useStyle();
    return <div>
       <Drawer
          open={this.props.DrawerOpen}
          anchor="right"
          variant="persistent"
          onClose={this.fixthew}
          className = {classes.drawer}
       >
          ---some element------
       </Drawer>
    <\div>
}


function PageMenu(){
    return(
         <div>
            <MenuItems/>
         </div>
    )
}
```

if you are a beginner i can advice you to use functional component with hooks and learn the diffrences...
also, Matirial-Ui is a tough Library u better learn the customizations in this library and the ways they offer to style components... (there is many though..)

Comment: how should i change the style of the material ui in class component?

Comment: withStyles as Nazeer said...
u just need to look into in the the docs and see how to do it correctly... anyways i asrresed you the mistakes u id so it can help you...